# Using Near_analysis under loop

Tags: arcpy, shortest-path

```
for i in range (1,7):
layer="s"+str(i)
arcpy.Near_analysis(layer,"Wall")
```

I have 6 layers labelled s1 to s6 representing 6 points. I'm using Near_analysis to calculate shortest distance of the points to a line. The first iteration returns a correct value for Near_dist. However, the second iteration changes the Near_dist value of previous layer to -1. Finally, only the last layer has the correct value and the others have -1

Comment: Can you provide more details of your inputs and expected outputs, perhaps including a picture, please?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to indent the lines after the for loop:

```
for i in range (1,7):
    layer="s"+str(i)
    arcpy.Near_analysis(layer,"Wall")
```

Comment: The indentation was fine. The loop executed for all the values. For some reason, it is changing the previous value during each iteration. I can even see the change from correct value to -1 as it progresses.

Comment: It seems when you paste your code in your question, it was not pasted correctly. You should use the code block {} to avoid any trouble in displaying the code. You can edit your question any time to reflect the problem with the correct code that you have.